# What is a single noun describing a "rate limit"?

Tags: nouns

I am looking for a suitable term for `API rate limit`.

> API Rate limit is a time gap between consecutive API calls.

Currently using `apiRateLimit="1000 miliseconds";`

Looking for something like `apiBar`.
**Is `bar` fit for the term?**

---

**`apiThresholdLimit`** -- a level, rate, or amount at which something comes into effect. << Still have two word.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to a different site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming things is listed as explicitly off-topic in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

This is really in some ways more a programming question than an English question, because "rate limit" is actually a well-defined technical term in programming contexts.  As such, there really isn't any other term that expresses the same thing with the same level of precision.  If you are limiting the frequency with which something like an API can be invoked, then "rate limit" really is the term you want that everyone will understand.

The only single-word term I can think of which might come close is "throttle", but this usually implies something that is either dynamically adjustable or only applied at certain times to slow things down.

Actually, based on your example code, you aren't actually defining a "rate" at all (a rate would generally be expressed as the number of events per time period), but instead what you have is an "interval".  If you want to be really correct, what that variable actually is would be a "rate limit interval" (3 words.  I know that makes things even worse.)

I'm curious, why is it so important to have a one-word term?  In my opinion, it's usually much more valuable to have things like variable and parameter names use well defined and understood terms, and be precise about what type of thing they actually are (e.g. "rate" vs "interval"), to avoid misunderstandings on the part of those using them (or trying to debug them later).  Word count generally shouldn't be high a priority...